# Why does my sticky menu jump left when changing to position:fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, sticky

I came across a strange behaviour on my site when trying to create a sticky menu. Well, a sticky menu is alright, but when it sticks (after scrolling page down) it suddenly moves to the left.

I think it is somehow related to changing style to position:fixed.
How can I make the menu to stay on the same size, centered, as it looks like when unsticked?

You can check the live demo [here](https://www.metroguides.net/ru/cities/bucharest-metro-romania). Thank you.

Comment: do you wan't to make it fit on all screen width or to be the same width before being sticky

Comment: Hello! Thanks for comment.
I want it to be the same width before sticky, not expanding it to all screen.

Comment: Could you please add the isStuck class and fixed position to `moduletable` class instead of `navigationbar ` class this will not solve the problem directly but it the first step.

Comment: Just added isStuck to moduletable. Seems to be the same result.

Comment: See, the problem with your layout is that the width is calculated based on paddings. When an element is set to `fixed` or `absolute` positioning, it will not inherit the calculated width with padding, padding will be ignored... in the future you could use `width:90%` instead of `padding-right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width 100% won't be effective because your layout has a sidebar so you need subtract sidebar and paddings width

```
.isStuck {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: calc(100% - 480px);
}
```

Comment: that seemed to help, but when we're back to top menu does not look like it was. It goes to the left.

Comment: please add this width to your current link and I will check it again

Comment: Just added. Please check.
That did the trick but it is not responsive at all. Is is possible to make it responsive (like using the percentage or smth.)?

Comment: which framework you are using for responsiveness or you working with your own media quires ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, give it a set `width`

```
.isStuck { width:100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've already tried it, but when I apply this style menu moves far away to the right. Check the link now and you'see how it works. [link](https://www.metroguides.net/ru/cities/bucharest-metro-romania)

Answer (score 0):

**Add specific styling for id #menu under @media query**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)
.isStuck #menu {
width: calc(100% - 480px);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) 
.isStuck { 
 z-index: 1000;
 width: calc( 100% - 8%); 
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer.
This is not correct because in this case when you scroll down menu also expands to the right, which is not an expected behaviour.

Comment: Did you try @Peter Wilson answer that seems to resolve your issue?

Comment: Just added. Please check.
That did the trick but it is not responsive at all. Is is possible to make it responsive (like using the percentage or smth.)?

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 769px)
.isStuck #menu {
    width: calc(100% - 480px);
}

It will not clash with your responsive styling.

Comment: yep, working. Now try to change to smaller resolution (when sidebar is hiding behind the button). How to make it behave the same on smaller resolutions? Thanks.

Comment: Similarly for 
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  .isStuck {
    z-index: 1000;
    width: calc( 100% - 8%);
}

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys so I made it working and fully responsive using your techniques and a little bit of @media queries. You guys are great, thanks for your help. Final code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .isStuck #menu { width: calc(100% - 480px); }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .isStuck #menu { width: calc(100% - 100px); }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px){
        .isStuck { width: calc(100% - 40px); }
}

@media (max-width: 480px){
        .isStuck { width: calc(100% - 50px); }
}
```